# AppEngine Log output?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've just followed this excellent tutorial:

```
http://www.rominirani.com/2009/10/31/episode-6-handling-incoming-email-in-your-application/
```

And I think my app is working. But he shows this as his output from his logs:

[image: Logoutput]

But I have this:

[image]
Do I assume its working or not, nothing seems to happen after I send it the first email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I hadn't changed the logging level in `logging.properties` to `.level = INFO`

Answer (score 1):

The message you are seeing in the log is a normal spawn instance message, nothing to be alert about.

Comment: And if I'm not seeing the other messages its probably not working?

Comment: @EricBanderhide it depends on your logging, if you suppose to have logs on each mail received and you are not seeing it then its probably not working.